# ASP.NET MVC: What is the web.config within views used for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC. Yes, I know its been around for a while but until recently I did not have to work on it. My verdict?

For the last 3 days I have been struggling to get my app to work on IIS. It's working in production. It works when I run it in VS. It just refuses to work if I redeploy it on iis. It's not the iis itself because the prev version runs perfect. It kept on giving me the 500 error with the wording:

[image]

Very clear what the error is, yes? Freaking No !

I have spend hours on hours over the last 3 days combing the internet for a solution. The most comments and accepted answers is that the ASP.NET MVC version in the `web.config` (view folder) differs etc. etc. If I look at it in VS, its the same as in production so that was not the cause.

A long story short: in the end the `web.config` in the views folder is not being deployed with my deployment package to iis. The cause is a purposeful exclusion of `web.config` files from the deployment package. This is a rule to prevent dev or qa setting entering the production environment. Because of this rule I manually copy the web.config...you know, the actual useful one that has the db connections, SSRS version info etc.

After copying the `web.config` from the view folder from the development machine manually and recycling the app pool the app worked.

**My question**: exactly what is the purpose of the web.config file in the views folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the web.config file found in the Views folder as part of your deployment.